# How to modify a column for a join in spark dataframe when the join key are given as a list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, inner-join

I have been trying to join two dataframes using the following list of join key passed as a list and I want to add the functionality to join on a subset of the keys if one of the key value is null

I have been trying to join two dataframes df_1 and df_2.

```
data1 = [[1,'2018-07-31',215,'a'],
        [2,'2018-07-30',None,'b'],
        [3,'2017-10-28',201,'c']
     ]
df_1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data1, 
['application_number','application_dt','account_id','var1'])
```

and

```
data2 = [[1,'2018-07-31',215,'aaa'],
        [2,'2018-07-30',None,'bbb'],
        [3,'2017-10-28',201,'ccc']
        ]
df_2 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data2, 
['application_number','application_dt','account_id','var2'])
```

The code I use to join is this:

```
key_a = ['application_number','application_dt','account_id']
new = df_1.join(df_2,key_a,'left')
```

The output for the same is:

```
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|application_number|application_dt|account_id|var1|var2|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|                 1|    2018-07-31|       215|   a| aaa|
|                 3|    2017-10-28|       201|   c| ccc|
|                 2|    2018-07-30|      null|   b|null|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
```

My concern here is, in the case where account_id is null, the join should still work by comparing other 2 keys.

The required output should be like this:

```
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|application_number|application_dt|account_id|var1|var2|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|                 1|    2018-07-31|       215|   a| aaa|
|                 3|    2017-10-28|       201|   c| ccc|
|                 2|    2018-07-30|      null|   b| bbb|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
```

I have found a similar approach to do so by using the statement:

```
  join_elem = "df_1.application_number == 
  df_2.application_number|df_1.application_dt == 
  df_2.application_dt|F.coalesce(df_1.account_id,F.lit(0)) ==  
  F.coalesce(df_2.account_id,F.lit(0))".split("|")
  join_elem_column = [eval(x) for x in join_elem]
```

But the design consideration do not allow me to use a full join expression and i am stuck with using the list of column names as join-key.

I have been trying to find a way to accommodate this coalesce thing into this list itself but have not found any success so far.

Comment: Why not join on the other keys and then filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this solution a workaround.

The issue here is that we have `Null` value for one of the keys in the `DataFrame` and the OP wants that rest of the key columns to be used instead. Why not assign an arbitrary value to this `Null` and then apply the join. Effectively this would be same thing like making a join on the remaining two keys.

```
# Let's replace Null with an arbitrary value, which has
# little chance of occurring in the Dataset. For eg; -100000
df1 = df1.withColumn('account_id', when(col('account_id').isNull(),-100000).otherwise(col('account_id')))    
df2 = df2.withColumn('account_id', when(col('account_id').isNull(),-100000).otherwise(col('account_id')))

# Do a FULL Join
df = df1.join(df2,['application_number','application_dt','account_id'],'full')

# Replace the arbitrary value back with Null.    
df = df.withColumn('account_id', when(col('account_id')== -100000, None).otherwise(col('account_id')))
df.show()
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|application_number|application_dt|account_id|var1|var2|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
|                 1|    2018-07-31|       215|   a| aaa|
|                 2|    2018-07-30|      null|   b| bbb|
|                 3|    2017-10-28|       201|   c| ccc|
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+----+
```